# Input placeholder tag in html

Tags: css, html, input

I have given 100% width to input box to fix to the browser width but when i add placeholder, the input box is going out of the browser width and horizontal scroll bar is coming. 
I don't want scroll bar to occur. Any idea??

here is my input tag

```
 <input type="tel" tabindex="9" maxlength="12" placeholder="XXX-XXX-XXXX" value="" name="mobileNumber" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `box-sizing:border-box` property for this.Write like this:

```
input{
    width:100%;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/9rprY/ .

But it's not work in IE7 & below.

Answer (score 0):

Make it 98% instead of 100%. If you set the width to 100%, it means the content width, and the total width occupied by the element is that 100% plus twice the border width plus twice the padding. The value of 98% is of course just a guess, but usually good enough.

There are other, better approaches. For usability, the visible width should reflect the width of expected normal input, so it should sufficient to set the `width` attribute in HTML to a suitable number. (The value depends on what kinds of numbers you expect; international telephone numbers can be rather long.)

Answer (score 0):

Using css3 property box-sizing you can redefine what width means to include the external padding and border(not margin).

```
input{
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Unfortunately because it's CSS3, this property don't support by all IE (IE6 and IE7 don't support). You can read more about it here: [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp?output=print)